# JavaScript get elements by class not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get some images to work with lightbox but I do not want all images on that site to react to the eventlistener.

This is how my images are declared:

```html
<img class="thumbnail" id="imga" src="~/lib/images/IC/Bild1,5_Pirellival.png"/>
```

This is what I tried but it is not working:

```js
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')
```

I do not want to use `querySelectorAll('img')` because this would mess up my other images on the same page.

Any advice?

Comment: Why not use `querySelectorAll('.thumbnail')`?

Comment: You haven't defined what you mean by "not working," but `document.getElementsByClassName` isn't broken. If there are elements in the document with that class, they **will** be in the `HTMLCollection` it returns. So presumably, they aren't in the document (yet?).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - They could, but if `getElementsByClassName` isn't finding them, `querySelectorAll` won't either. :-) Though there is the distinction between the live collection from the former and the snapshot from the latter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, I've been around this block a few times too. Just trying to gently introduce the concept of using class selectors with `querySelectorAll`. There's really not enough in the question to indicate which collection type they need.